# Регулярные выражения: только кириллица и тире

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, html-form

Делаю валидацию формы Имя Фамилия(поле text). В поле может быть введены только русские буквы, тире и пробел. Текста может быть сколько угодно много

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать регулярку? Моя регулярка работает, но когда добавляю `\-`, чтобы можно было тире ставить - пропускает латиницу

```
^[a-яА-Я\-]+\s[a-яА-Я\-]+
```

Comment: А если `pattern="[a-яёА-ЯЁ-]+\s[a-яёА-ЯЁ-]+"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше регулярное выражение

```
^[a-яА-Я\-]+\s[a-яА-Я\-]+
```

Экранирование `-` можно не делать, если тире будет находится сразу после квадратной скобки или в конце.
В диапазоне А-Я не содержится буква Ё, ее нужно указывать отдельно.

```html
<form>
  <input 
      id="choose"
      name="i_like"
      required 
      pattern="[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+\s[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+"
      title="Кириллица разделенная одиночным пробелом"
  >
  <button>Тык</button>
</form>
```

```
[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+\s[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+
```

`^` - начало строки
`[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+`  - одна и более буква кириллицы в верхнем и нижнем регистре  или знака `-`
`\s` - пробельный символ
`[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+` - одна и более буква кириллицы в верхнем и нижнем регистре  или знака `-`

---

Под данное регулярное выражение будет валидным ввод `- -`
Поэтому тире так же следует добавить в отдельную группу, что бы после него шли буквенные символы:

```regex
[а-яА-ЯЁё]+(-[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+)?\s[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+(-[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+)?
```

Теперь тире может быть установлено только в середину слова

```html
<form>
  <input 
      id="choose"
      name="i_like"
      required 
      pattern="[а-яА-ЯЁё]+(-[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+)?\s[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+(-[а-яА-ЯЁё-]+)?"
      title="Кириллица разделенная одиночным пробелом"
  >
  <button>Тык</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не нужны тут ни `^`, ни `$`. В `pattern` выражение должно находить совпадение целого текста автоматически.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, понял, спасибо!